# Detect if factor level is numeric or string in R

Tags: r

I have some data in R that comes with special strings for missing data. I want to `subset` the original dataframe into a **valid data** and one with only the **missing data**.

In the following example, I have some numeric values, and two strings for missing data (`MD1` and `MD2`).

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c( 1, 2, 3, "MD1", 5, "MD2"))
```

If there were only a few such strings, I could enumerate them and extract the subsets (this is not how I did it, but it's simple and fits the purpose of this question):

```
DF.invalid <- droplevels( subset(DF, x == "MD1" | x == "MD2") )
DF.valid <- subset(DF, x != "MD1" & x != "MD2")
DF.valid$x <- as.numeric(levels(DF.valid$x))[DF.valid$x]
```

My problem is that the missing data strings may not be known in advance. Is there a proper (elegant) way to detect that `MD1` and `MD2` are non-numeric and achieve this results, without inspecting the dataframe and enumerating the non-numeric levels?

Comment: Do `as.numeric(levels(df$x)[df$x])`, and those that become `NA` are non-numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `x` be a factor column "with mixed numeric and character levels" (actually all levels are character) of a data frame `dat`.

To extract "character levels", use:

```
na.idx <- is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(levels(x))))
non.num.levels <- levels(x)[na.idx]
```

If you want to subset `dat` with those levels, you can use

```
subset(dat, x %in% non.num.levels)
```

but a better way is via:

```
subset(dat, na.idx[x])
```

Comment: In your opinion, should I be using data.table here, instead of data.frames?